# JMeter Hbase scan sampler fails with ClassNotFoundException exception

Tags: jmeter, hbase, apache-zookeeper, hadoop2, jmeter-plugins

I'm trying to use Hadoop/Hbase sampler to connect and scan the tables created in Hbase, however my test is failing with the following messages.

Checked the configuration of Hadoop/Hbase all the service are running and listening to the appropriate port. (zookeeper is running and listening to 2181).

```
2016/04/02 15:44:04 ERROR - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Test failed! java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/configuration/Configuration
at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.DefaultMetricsSystem.<init>(DefaultMetricsSystem.java:37)
at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.DefaultMetricsSystem.<clinit>(DefaultMetricsSystem.java:34)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UgiInstrumentation.create(UgiInstrumentation.java:51)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.initialize(UserGroupInformation.java:217)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.ensureInitialized(UserGroupInformation.java:185)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.isSecurityEnabled(UserGroupInformation.java:237)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.KerberosName.<clinit>(KerberosName.java:79)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.initialize(UserGroupInformation.java:210)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.ensureInitialized(UserGroupInformation.java:185)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.isSecurityEnabled(UserGroupInformation.java:237)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser(UserGroupInformation.java:482)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser(UserGroupInformation.java:468)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Methods.call(Methods.java:37)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.User.call(User.java:590)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.User.callStatic(User.java:580)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.User.access$400(User.java:51)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.User$SecureHadoopUser.<init>(User.java:397)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.User$SecureHadoopUser.<init>(User.java:392)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.User.getCurrent(User.java:140)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionKey.<init>(HConnectionManager.java:435)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager.getConnection(HConnectionManager.java:180)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.<init>(HTable.java:155)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTableFactory.createHTableInterface(HTableFactory.java:36)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTablePool.createHTable(HTablePool.java:265)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTablePool.findOrCreateTable(HTablePool.java:195)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTablePool.getTable(HTablePool.java:174)
at com.atlantbh.jmeter.plugins.hbasecomponents.config.HBaseConnectionVariable.getTable(HBaseConnectionVariable.java:43)
at com.atlantbh.jmeter.plugins.hbasecomponents.samplers.HBaseScanSampler.sample(HBaseScanSampler.java:94)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:434)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:261)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.configuration.Configuration
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 35 more**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is on your JMeter side. As the error message states:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.configuration.Configuration

which means that HBase Scan Sampler requires [Apache Commons Configuration](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/) library, but looks like Hadoop plug-in does not provide it in its [zip package](http://jmeter-plugins.org/downloads/all/). Try to ask on their [forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/jmeter-plugins) if they are willing to fix it.

For now as a workaround you can:

1. [Download](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/download_configuration.cgi) commons-configuration2-2.0-bin.zip from the site
2. Unzip it
3. Copy `commons-configuration2-2.0.jar` into `.../apache-jmeter/lib`
4. Restart jmeter

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Encountered the same exception even after copying the commons-configuration. Any suggestions?. Meanwhile i started a trail with JMeter-Plugins group.

Comment: Did you try both versions available on that site (1.10 and 2.0)? We don't know which version of that package hadoop is using, so try both, but one by one (i.e. don't put both versions at the same time into lib).

Comment: Kiril, Thanks. Your suggestion worked!... After copying 1.10 version it did not report the commons-configuration exception. Thanks again.